# Max- Min Optimization problem

Tags: optimization

I am a noob in mathematic, so I would need your help in solving the optimization problem below

\begin{array}{l}
\max\limits_{\bf l} \min \left( \left| {\bf g}_1 {\bf Ml} \right|^2, \left| {\bf g}_2 \bf Ml \right|^2 \right) \\
\text{ s.t. } \left\| {\bf Ml} \right\|^2 = \text{positive const}.
\end{array}

where ${\bf g}_1, {\bf g}_2 \in {^{1 \times M}}$ and ${\bf M} \in {^{M \times 2}}$ are given vectors and matrix, $\bf{l}$ has the size $2\times1$.

Many thanks for your help,
Anh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transform the problem by introducing a new decision variable $z$ which captures  $\min (|\mathbf{g}_1\mathbf{Ml}|^2,|\mathbf{g}_2 \mathbf{Ml}|^2)$. Your problem now becomes
$$
\max_{\mathbf{l},z} z
$$
subject to:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\|\mathbf{Ml}\|^2 &=k \\
z &\le |\mathbf{g}_1 \mathbf{Ml}|^2 \\
z &\le |\mathbf{g}_2 \mathbf{Ml}|^2
\end{aligned} 
$$

Comment: Thank you Michael, I think the first constraint must be $\|\mathbf{Ml}\|^2 &=k$. And what should I do next?

Comment: If you need the actual numerical answer, plug this model into a convex solver like BARON or LOQO. If you'd like an analytical solution, try to form the Lagrangian and write the KKT conditions. Don't forget to upvote and mark the question as answered, if the proposed solution makes sense for you.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try to follow your instruction.